# Linux Terminal Input/Output C program

Tags: c, terminal, pthreads, buffer, printf

I am having some doubts about Linux Terminal output's

in a c program i made a

```
printf("Write A Message"); 
fgets(buffer,BUFSIZ,stdin);
```

which waits for a Message to be typed from keyboard
I have threads on background which give back a ouptut, is it posible to output their message's in the terminal during the input? Without messing out the inserted words.

Cause is on a Server, and Someone can write commands in the Server

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your threads also print to the terminal, the output will show up on the screen and mess up what is there. So if you wait for a keypress and in the meantime threads are printing, the message may dissapear.